# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\BatterFirst::index()

Tags: laravel-8

I want to add some data but I got
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\BatterFirst::index()
error
where my model BatterFirst.php is

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BatterFirst extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'runs', 'balls', 'sixs', 'fours'
    ];
}
```

This is my controller BatterFirstController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\BatterFirst;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BatterFirstController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = BatterFirst::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('BatterFirst.index',compact('data'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('BatterFirst.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'runs' => 'required',
            'balls' => 'required',
            'sixs' => 'required',
            'fours' => 'required',

        ]);

        BatterFirst::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('BatterFirst.index')
                        ->with('success','Batter created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\BatterFirst  $batterFirst
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        return view('BatterFirst.show',compact('BatterFirst'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\BatterFirst  $batterFirst
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        return view('BatterFirst.edit',compact('BatterFirst'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\BatterFirst  $batterFirst
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'runs' => 'required',
            'balls' => 'required',
            'sixs' => 'required',
            'fours' => 'required',
        ]);

        $batterFirst->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('BatterFirst.index')
                        ->with('success','Batter updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\BatterFirst  $batterFirst
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        $batterFirst->delete();

        return redirect()->route('BatterFirst.index')
                        ->with('success','Batter deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

This is my web.php

```
<?php

use App\Models\BatterFirst;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('BatterFirst', BatterFirst::class);
```

This is my BatterFrist/index.php

```
@extends('BatterFirst.layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5rem;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD Example from scratch - laravelcode.com</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('BatterFirst.create') }}"> Create New Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Runs</th>
            <th>Balls</th>
            <th>Sixs</th>
            <th>Fours</th>
            <th>Strick Rate</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->runs }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->overs }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->balls }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->sixs }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->fours }}</td>
            {{-- <td>{{ $value->runs/$value->balls*100 }}</td> --}}
            <td>@if ($value->runs > 0 and $value->runs ==0)
                    {{ $value->runs*100 }}
                @elseif ($value->balls>0 and $value->runs ==0)
                    {{ $value->balls*$value->runs }}
                @elseif ($value->balls==0 and $value->runs ==0)
                    {{ $value->balls *  $value->runs }}
                @elseif ($value->runs>0 and $value->balls>=0)
                    {{ $value->runs/$value->balls*100 }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('BatterFirst.destroy',$value->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('BatterFirst.show',$value->id) }}">Show</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('BatterFirst.edit',$value->id) }}">Edit</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {!! $data->links() !!}
@endsection
```

What is the problem here? Thanks for helping me.
If you need anything more like more detailed code then ask me I will update it.
Note: I am just a beginner at laravel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the controller in web.php not model

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BatterFirstController;

Route::resource('BatterFirst', [BatterFirstController::class]);
```

Now you can call from any where e.g
In example.blade.php file

```
<a href={{'BatterFirst.index'}}>Index<a/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's debug your code, starting where a request comes in to the application - at the routes file:

```
Route::resource('BatterFirst', BatterFirst::class);
```

You have a `resource()` route handled by `BatterFirst::class`.  But where is that class?  It has to map to something, and if you look at the top of that same routes file we see:

```
use App\Models\BatterFirst;
```

So a request for `yoursite.com/BatterFirst/` will be handled by the `index()` method in your `BatterFirst` model.  But of course there is no such method.

Stepping back, it is obvious you want the *Controller* to handle your routes, not your *Model*.  Remove that `use` line at the top of your routes file, and replace it with:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BatterFirstController;
```

And update your routes to be handled by that controller:

```
Route::resource('BatterFirst', BatterFirstController::class);
```